# DSpace 7.1 AIP restore StackOverflowError

Tags: backup, stack-overflow, restore, dspace

I try to migrate from DSpace 6.4 to 7.1. New Dspace is installed on other machine (virtual machine on Centos 7 with 8Gb of RAM)
I have created full site AIP backup with user passwords. (total size of packages - 11Gb)

I've tried to do full restore but always got the same error.
So I'm just trying to import only "first level without childs"

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -Xss4m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" /dspace/bin/dspace packager -r -k  -t AIP -e dinkwi.test@gmail.com -o skipIfParentMissing=true -i 123456789/0  /home/dimich/11111/repo.zip
```

It doesn't matter if I use `-k` or `-f` param, output ia always the same

```
Ingesting package located at /home/dimich/11111/repo.zip
Exception: null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.dspace.eperson.GroupServiceImpl.getChildren(GroupServiceImpl.java:788)
        at org.dspace.eperson.GroupServiceImpl.getChildren(GroupServiceImpl.java:802)
.... (more then 1k lines)
        at org.dspace.eperson.GroupServiceImpl.getChildren(GroupServiceImpl.java:802)
```

my dspace.log ended with

```
2021-12-20 11:05:28,141 INFO  unknown unknown org.dspace.eperson.GroupServiceImpl @ dinkwi.test@gmail.com::update_group:group_id=9e6a2038-01d9-41ad-96b9-c6fb55b44381
2021-12-20 11:05:30,048 INFO  unknown unknown org.dspace.eperson.GroupServiceImpl @ dinkwi.test@gmail.com::update_group:group_id=23aaa7e9-ca2d-4af5-af64-600f7126e2be
2021-12-20 11:05:30,800 INFO  unknown unknown org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean @ Shutting down EhCache CacheManager 'org.dspace.services'
```

So I just want to figure out the problem: small stack or some bug in user/group that fails with infinite loop/recursion, or maybe something else...

Main problem - i'm good in php/mysql and have no experience with java/postgre and the way how to debug this ...

Any help would be appreciated.

p.s after failed restore I always run command

```
/dspace/bin/dspace cleanup -v
```

Comment: Try with this parameters: `dspace packager -r -a -f -t AIP -o createMetadataFields=true -o skipIfParentMissing=true`

Comment: thank you, but it will not help. It turned out, that I can not add new group. Logs show the same error. So  - only deep debugging.

Comment: I found problem in table group2group where was one logical mistake: parent_id has child_id and where was another record where this child_id has its own child with parent_id value. So - I removed this record from table and adding new group became possible. I hope import/export will work coorectly